# GStreamer-sharp freezes on seeking with SeekFlags.Flush

Tags: c#, gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

I'm trying, as a practice, to convert GStreamer examples from c to c#, and I'm stuck on the Basic tutorial 4 (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/time-management.html).
In the example the seeking is performed as follows

```
gst_element_seek_simple (data.playbin, GST_FORMAT_TIME,
          GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT, 30 * GST_SECOND);
```

which I translated to C#:

```
playbin.SeekSimple(Format.Time, SeekFlags.Flush | SeekFlags.KeyUnit, 30L * Constants.SECOND);
```

However, after seeking, only one frame is played, and then the playback freezes.

There is a C# tutorial here: (https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp/blob/master/samples/BasicTutorial4.cs). However, in this tutorial seeking is performed without the `SeekFlags.Flush` (in line 73). The seeking in the example works, but it is performed with a delay of a few seconds.

So, does the `SeekFlags.Flush` work in the C# GStreamer bindings or am I missing something here?

I have installed the latest GStreamer and GstSharp (version 1.14.0).

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, by rebuilding from the gstreamer-sharp source (https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp).

I converted to .netstandard 2.0 and added Nuget package GioSharp (https://www.nuget.org/packages/GioSharp/3.22.24.36)

Alternatively, I rebuild the original gstreamer-sharp project and GtkSharp.Win32 Nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/GtkSharp.Win32/3.1.2)

Hope it finds its way in the official GstSharp Nuget package.